# C++ warning non-static data member initializers

Tags: c++, g++, gcc-warning, non-static

I wrote a C++ program and when I compiled it, I got this warning wherever I call `Vector3* center = new Vector3()`, actually anywhere I call Vector3() constructor:

`warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   Vector3* center = new Vector3();`

Here is my **Vector3.h:**

```
class Vector3  {
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

public:

    // Constructors & Destructor
    Vector3(float x,float y,float z);
    Vector3();
    ~Vector3(){}
    // getters & setters & some other functions
};
```

And my **Vector3.cpp:**

```
#include "vector3.h"

Vector3::Vector3(){
    this->x = 0.0;
    this->y = 0.0;
    this->z = 0.0;
}

Vector3::Vector3(float x,float y,float z)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}
// others
```

My command to compile is as follows:

```
g++ -O2 main.cpp vector3.cpp
```

Deleting the `Vector3()` constructor completely and calling `Vector3* v = new Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` also didn't worked, I got the same warning.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** This is a homework and I can't use C++ 11. This program will be tested in department computers which haven't C++ 11.

Comment: [C++11 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). Also, your compiler message clearly states how to fix the issue.

Comment: The warning is coming from an entirely different place (it has to be in main.cpp, because you compile only two files).

Comment: @kalahari I do not even see where in your code there is such a statement like this   Vector3* v = new Vector3():

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, **complete**, and **verifiable** example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited the question. Also changed a little bit for @VladfromMoscow

Comment: This is a ray tracer. There are plenty of classes and code. I call the constructor inside other classes or functions.

Comment: @kalahari You have not edited it in a way to make the example complete or verifiable. We can't help you fix the problem if we can't even see where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you all, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is implying this line
`Vector3* center = new Vector3();`
was directly in a class definition.  That line would be OK inside a function definition (even if the function definition is inside a class definition).

Did you intend that line to be directly inside a class?  That means `center` is a member of that class and the `new Vector3()` will be executed by default by every constructor of that class (but only in C++11 or later).

If all that is what you intended, then inside `class whatever {` you need to change the declaration of `center` to be just `Vector3* center;` and then you need to edit every constructor of `whatever` from something like `whatever::whatever(...) {` to `whatever::whatever(...) : center(new Vector3()) {`

But if you didn't intend that definition of `center` to be defining a member of a class (if you intended it to define a local variable in a function), review and/or post the context of that line so you can get a more informed answer.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now.